# can i make my app to get opened via browser in Android?

Tags: android

i have developed an app ,which has to get opened when user enters url like myappurl://  in browser like chrome or internet.Can this happen in android devices?if it so how please guide me in this i have referred below links but no luck.

[Not getting opened installed Android App via browser in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33275318/not-getting-opened-installed-android-app-via-browser-in-android/33275496?noredirect=1#comment54374774_33275496)

[Launch custom android application from android browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958701/launch-custom-android-application-from-android-browser)

my requirement is very similar to this [Launching custom Android application from Android browser / Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21663001/launching-custom-android-application-from-android-browser-chrome)

i tried this things but it opens website of that address i want to make my app to get opened

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intent filters for `ACTION_VIEW` works only for **clicking** URLs and **not copying or typing** them in the address bar of the browser.

browsers generate respective intent only on URL click events.

**Note :** this observation is for chrome and default browser of android

Comment: there is no InternetExplorer on Android!

Comment: my observation is for chrome and default browser of android. may be browsers you have mentioned have implemented handling of `ACTION_VIEW ` from address bar, so if may differ from browser to browser and one can not do much about it.

Comment: @Rahul Tiwari is there any other way of doing this? when i googled about it said me to use iframes with src, refer this link https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents but even after googling about it i didnt get any idea on how to do this

Comment: @Kitesurfer i mean default internet explorer installed in android devices

Comment: as I said it will work for click of URL on those browsers. so you can change your workflow in a manner that involves clicking a URL instead of entering one.

Comment: @Rahul Tiwari thanks for your explaination after reading it i was then able to understand that it  works only for clicking URLs and not copying or typing them.